# Change UINavigationBar back button text and font from AppDelegate using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to change UINavigationBar back bar button text from `AppDelegate` to apply changes to all the `Views` in my app.

I've changed the title font style using:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "MyCustomFont", size: 20)!
]
```

But I don't know how to access to the left bar button to make changes on it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Swift 3.0,4.0**

Simply you can achieve it with `extension` of `UINavigationItem`. According to many search there is no way to change left button text with app delegate.

```
extension UINavigationItem{

    override open func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backItem.title = "Hello"


        if let font = UIFont(name: "Copperplate-Light", size: 32){
            backItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:font], for: .normal)
        }else{

            print("Font Not available")
        }
        /*Changing color*/
        backItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green], for: .normal)

        self.backBarButtonItem = backItem
    }

}
```

**Update:**

You can change Back Button arrow colour from `AppDelegate` on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`,

```
 /*It will change back arrow color only if you use  backItem.setTitleTextAttributes, else it will change whole text color*/
 UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.orange
```

Comment: The back arrow is not changing the color, how can I do that?

Comment: Have spent way too long trying other answers. The AppDelegate approach does not work at all. This is the only approach that has worked for me. However, one detail missing to avoid the font changing to the default system font when pressed: backItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font:font], for: .selected)

Answer (score 2):

> To change the image color you can either use the font file and change
>   the color or use the image with the color you needed.

```
let yourBackButtonIcon = //YourImage here
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = yourBackButtonIcon
navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = yourBackButtonIcon
```

> To change the back button title text color

```
navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: yourFont,
NSForegroundColorAttributeName: yourColor]
```

**Note:-**

> Above code should be inside the `AppDelegate` class of
>   `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "MyCustomFont", size: 20)!], for: .normal)
```

Comment: Thank you! But I want to change only the back button in the left and add a text to it, not only style.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Subclass the `UINavigationController` and use it. Then make your viewDidLoad like so: (change the attributes according to your need)

   ```
   //
   //  NavConViewController.swift
   //  customattributedbackbtn
   //
   //  Created by Glenn Posadas on 8/12/17.
   //  Copyright © 2017 Glenn Posadas. All rights reserved.
   //

   import UIKit

   class NavConViewController: UINavigationController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Light", size: 12)!
           var attributes: [String : Any] = [NSFontAttributeName : font]

           attributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.black

           UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self, NavConViewController.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
       }
   }
   ```

Sample output:

**Default**

[image]

**Attributed**

[image]