# UIBarButtonItem remove Back Button Title - iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

```
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
```

I use above to remove the `backButtonTitle` prior to iOS 11. But on iOS 11 that is not properly working.
Arrow shifts bit downwards.
[image]
How to fix this?

Edit: Other way by erasing Title can solve my problem but my concern is why that old way is not working anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UINavigationBar Hide back Button Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853617/uinavigationbar-hide-back-button-text)

Comment: @Luzo I have to edit every VCs for that. I don't want to do it by that method.

Comment: @Nitesh You can use common superclass. Or you can subclass `UINavigatonController` and make the magic happen there. Even if you had to edit every VC, it would be better than your original hacky solution.

Comment: See Here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45651186/6479530

Comment: This one is much better: UIOffsetMake(-1000, 0)

Answer (score 4):

The other way is to set `UINavigationControllerDelegate` for your navigationController and erase the title in its function.

```
class NoBackButtonTitleNavigationDelegate: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(
        _ navigationController: UINavigationController,
        willShow viewController: UIViewController,
        animated: Bool
    ) {
        viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Best solution I have seen for that question.

Comment: It tells me that: Type 'NoBackButtonTitleNavigationDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol' and then it adds a lot of Method stubs

Comment: Nico, all you have to do is implement the delegate for example: class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate{     
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.delegate = self
}

func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    } }


that shuld work

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
var newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.back))
navigationItem?.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

Comment: leftBarButtonItem and backBarButtonItem don't have the same padding

Answer (score 0):

Create Navigation controller class as below. Assign this "CustomNavViewController" to UINavigationController in your StoryBoard

```
class CustomNavViewController: UINavigationController,UINavigationControllerDelegate 
{


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func navigationController(
    _ navigationController: UINavigationController,
    willShow viewController: UIViewController,
    animated: Bool
    ) {
    viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

}

So, no need to do it in every viewControllers.
At last remove below line from AppDelegate class if present,

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving title vertically you can move horizontally. Also in case the title is long you can make its color transparent. Works just fine me:

```
let barButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
    barButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
    barButtonItemAppearance.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(-200, 0), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
```